# Filter Top N for visualisation

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have table as below:

[image]

In the table, I calculated count of the quarter 4 only for each "Level_2_tag". So now I want to create a slicer which filter top n to show on visualization. Top N will be based on the latest period of the timeline we choose. In this case, it will be Quarter 4. For example, if I put 5 in dynamic top N slicer, Visualization will only show Monthly Dosing, Budget, Adherence, ACS Patient and Adult quarter by quarter. Because 5 of them have highest count in quarter 4.

Is there anyway we can do it? I realize we can do it by using filter panel but I want to create a slicer for dynamic purpose.

Thanks

I tried calculated last quarter for all "LV2_tag" and rankx. But when I put it to filter, It didn't give me the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a measure that calculates the count for each Level_2_tag for the latest quarter. (assuming you have the YourCountMeasure already)

```
Count_Latest_Quarter = CALCULATE(
    [YourCountMeasure], 
    FILTER(
        All(Table),
        Table[Quarter] = "Q4"
    )
)
```

Then, you'll need a measure to dynamically rank the Level_2_tags based on the previous measure.

```
Rank_Latest_Quarter = RANKX(
    ALL(Table[Level_2_tag]), 
    [Count_Latest_Quarter], 
    , DESC, Dense
)
```

Then you need to create a What-If Parameter for the Top N Selection that you will use it to create a measure that will return true for items within the Top N based on the slicer value :

```
Is_Top_N = IF(
    [Rank_Latest_Quarter] <= [Top N Value],
    TRUE(),
    FALSE()
)
```

Comment: I have tried this, but for all Quarter except quarter 4, when we do rankx, they will return "1". So when we put it in the visualization, the chart still show other tags from quarter 1 to quarter 3.

Comment: Can you share data not in a picture ? and what is exactly your expected output ? help us to help you